# Login redirecting in cakePHP 3.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.2, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.3, cakephp-3.4

I'm trying to redirect to current page after logged in, using cakephp 3.4 but I'm getting like this

> localhost page isn't working, locahost page redirecting you too many
>   times. Try clearing your cookies

for 2 sec after that it's redirecting to home page. Please help me out here.
Here my code

In appController.php

```
public function initialize()
{ 
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ],
                'scope' => ['userStatus' => '1']
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer(),
        'logoutRedirect'       => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action'     => 'login'
        ]
    ]);
}
```

In loginController.php

```
function login{ 
 if ( $this->request->is( 'post' ) ) {
    if ( $this->Auth->login() ) 
    {
       $this->redirect($this->referer());
    } 
    else {
      $this->Flash->error(__('Your username or password is incorrect.'));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Related question :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49257722/redirect-to-referrer-not-working-after-login/49291597#49291597 , you may find the answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you got some redirect loop here. You should use `AuthComponent::redirectUrl()`.

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();

        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'));
        }
    }
}
```

See the [Redirecting Users After Login](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#redirecting-users-after-login) in the Documentation.

> After logging a user in, you’ll generally want to redirect them back
>   to where they came from. Pass a URL in to set the destination a user
>   should be redirected to after logging in.
>
> If no parameter is passed, the returned URL will use the following
>   rules:
>
> - Returns the normalized URL from the redirect query string value if it
>     is present and for the same domain the current app is running on.
>     Before 3.4.0, the `Auth.redirect` session value was used.
> - If there is no query string/session value and there is a config `loginRedirect`, the `loginRedirect` value is returned.
> - If there is no redirect value and no `loginRedirect`, `/` is returned.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now everything working fine but getting null query parameter string even though passing  query parameter string like this `login?redirect=%2Farticles%2Fadd`. Do you have any idea that where it would be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$this->Auth->redirectUrl()` instead of `$this->referer()`.

After logging a user in, you’ll generally want to redirect them back to where they came from. Pass a URL in to set the destination a user should be redirected to after logging in.

- Returns the normalized URL from the redirect query string value if it is present and for the same domain the current app is running on. Before 3.4.0, the Auth.redirect session value was used.
- If there is no query string/session value and there is a config loginRedirect, the loginRedirect value is returned.
- If there is no redirect value and no `loginRedirect`, `/` is returned.

Add to your `AuthComponent` configuration options:

**loginRedirect**

> The URL (defined as a string or array) to the controller action users
>   should be redirected to after logging in. This value will be ignored
>   if the user has an Auth.redirect value in their session.

Your code should be like that:

In appController.php

```
public function initialize()
{ 
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ],
                'scope' => ['userStatus' => '1']
            ]
        ],
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ],
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => $this->referer(),
        'logoutRedirect'       => [
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action'     => 'login'
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display'     
        ]
    ]);
}
```

In loginController.php

```
function login{ 
 if ( $this->request->is( 'post' ) ) {
    if ( $this->Auth->login() ) 
    {
       $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    } 
    else {
      $this->Flash->error(__('Your username or password is incorrect.'));
    }
  }
}
```

See also [Redirecting Users After Login](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#redirecting-users-after-login)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now everything is working fine but getting null query parameter string even though passing  query parameter string like this `login?redirect=%2Farticles%2Fadd`. Do you have any idea that where it would be wrong?

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve this value?

Comment: using `$this->request->query('redirect');`

Comment: Try to `$this->request->getQuery('redirect');`

Comment: Check `$this->request`

Comment: Very strange, I recommend you to open another question related to it, and if my answer solve your question problem, mark it as accepted.

Comment: @RayannNayran I am also facing the same problem, could you please help me to figure out the issue.
This is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49257722/redirect-to-referrer-not-working-after-login