# Avoid remember the previous route before login Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

how make the Auth Component in cake redirect to login page and don't keep the previous route. Example, if I going to index the Auth component redirect to `/users/login` instead of `/users/login?redirect=%2index` Thanks.

Comment: follow this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44263171/3278639

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider to **not** take into account the previous page and force redirect to a specific controller's action of your choice.

```
<?php
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'YourController', 'action' => 'YourAction']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid credentials.'));
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I do that but doesn't works. He still redirect to the previous route.